# Confused with Laravel's hasOne Eloquent Relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a new Laravel 5.8 application. I started playing with the Eloquent ORM and its relationships.

There is a problem right away that I encountered.

I have the following tables. (this is just an example, for testing reasons, not going to be an actual application)

```
Login table:
--------------------------
| id | user    | data_id |
--------------------------
| 1  | admin   | 1       |
| 2  | admin   | 2       |
| 3  | admin   | 3       |
--------------------------

Data table:
--------------
| id | ip_id |
--------------
| 1  | 1     |
| 2  | 2     |
| 3  | 3     |
--------------

IP table:
----------------------
| id | ip            |
----------------------
| 1  | 192.168.1.1   |
| 2  | 192.168.1.2   |
| 3  | 192.168.1.3   |
----------------------
```

What I wanted is to get the IP belonging to the actual login.

So I added a `hasOne` relationship to the `Login table` that has a foreign key  for the `Data table`:

```
public function data()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Data');
}
```

Then I added a `hasOne` relationship to the `Data table` that has a foreign key for the `IP table`:

```
public function ip()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Ip');
}
```

Once I was done, I wanted to retrieve the IP address for the first record of the Login table:

```
Login::find(1)->data()->ip()->get();
```

But I get this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::ip()
```

What am I missing here and how can I get the IP of that login in the correct way? Do I need a `belongsTo` somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 1st error: Wrong relationship definition

Laravel relationships are bi-directional. On `one-to-one` relationships, you can define the direct relationship (`HasOne`) and the inverse relationship (`BelongsTo`)

The direct relationship should be:

```
             HasOne                HasOne
[ Login ] <----------- [ Data ] <----------- [ IP ]
```

And the inverse relationship should be:

```
           BelongsTo             BelongsTo
[ Login ] -----------> [ Data ] -----------> [ IP ]
```

See [Eloquent: Relationships - One-to-One](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) docs for details on how defining it.

**Note** that you don't need to define both directions for a relationship unless you need it. In your case, I think you just need to define the `belongsTo` direction.

## 2nd error: You are calling the relationship method, not the relationship itself

When you do:

```
Login::find(1)->data()->ip()->get();
```

You are calling the method `data` that defines your relationship, not the related model. This is useful in some cases, but not on your case.

The correct is call the relationship magic property instead:

```
Login::find(1)->data->ip;
```

Note that we don't use the `()` and we do not need the `get()` here. Laravel takes care of loading it for us.

### Use Eager Loading

Laravel Eloquent have a [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for relationships that's very useful in some cases because it pre-loads your relationships, and reduce the quantity of queries you do.

In the situation that you described (loading a single `Login` model) it doesn't make any performance improvement, but also it doesn't slow down.

It's useful when you load many models, so it reduces your database query count from `N+1` to `2`.

Imagine that you are loading 100 `Login` models, without eager loading, you will do 1 query to get your `Login` models, 100 queries to get your `Data` models, and more 100 queries to get your `Ip` models.

With eager loading, it will do only 3 queries, causing a big performance increase.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the descriptive explanation, I understand it now. I think my problem in thinking was that I thought that the `Login` table is the 'main' table and the rest of it are parts of the Login table. Which is true, but need to think to do it inverse this case. Anyway, thank you so much for this, you saved my day! :)

Answer (score 2):

With your database structure:

Login `belongsTo` Data

Data `hasOne` Login

Data `belongsTo` IP

IP `hasOne` Data

After fixed your methods you can use of your relations like this

`$login = Login::with(['data.ip'])->find(1);`

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, I always have to have a belongsTo + a hasOne - and I can't have one without the other?

Comment: Also, where should I place the foreign keys? Or is it ok how I have them now?

Comment: @Radical_Activity please check https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

**Login**

```
public function data()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Data', 'data_id');
}
```

**Data**

```
public function ip()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Ip', 'ip_id');
}
```

```
$login = Login::with(['data.ip'])->find(1);
```

And inside `data` you will have `ip` like `$login->data->ip`.

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error message:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'data.login_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from 'data' where 'data'.'login_id' in (1))`

Comment: because you used `hasOne` method.